# Simple loop of object instances with if statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to OOP and want to create some simple HTML out of each object. Essentially, I have these objects:

```
const slides = {
  "slide1": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/winbledon-centre-court.jpg",
    "caption": "Wimbledon Centre Court"
  },
  "slide2": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/waterloo-train-station.jpg",
    "caption": "Waterloo Train Station"
  },
  "slide3": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/test.jpg",
    "caption": "Das Lion"
  },
  "slide4": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/some4.jpg",
    "caption": "the four"
  },
  "slide5": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/some5.jpg",
    "caption": "no five"
  }
}
```

And I just want the HTML to output this, where figure 1, 2 and 5 have unique classes:

```
"<figure class='individual-slide current'><img src='images/projects/authorising-engineers/winbledon-centre-court.jpg' style = 'background-image: url(images/projects/authorising-engineers/winbledon-centre-court.jpg)'><figcaption>Wimbledon Centre Court</figcaption></figure>"
"<figure class='individual-slide next'><img src='images/projects/authorising-engineers/waterloo-train-station.jpg' style = 'background-image: url(images/projects/authorising-engineers/waterloo-train-station.jpg)'><figcaption>Waterloo Train Station</figcaption></figure>"
"<figure class='individual-slide'><img src='images/projects/authorising-engineers/test.jpg' style = 'background-image: url(images/projects/authorising-engineers/test.jpg)'><figcaption>Das Lion</figcaption></figure>"
"<figure class='individual-slide'><img src='images/projects/authorising-engineers/some4.jpg' style = 'background-image: url(images/projects/authorising-engineers/some4.jpg)'><figcaption>the four</figcaption></figure>"
"<figure class='individual-slide previous'><img src='images/projects/authorising-engineers/some5.jpg' style = 'background-image: url(images/projects/authorising-engineers/some5.jpg)'><figcaption>no five</figcaption></figure>"
```

The closest I could achieve so far is the below - the following code successfully creates the HTML, but gives no control if I want to customise the nth item (i.e. adding classes to objects 1, 2 and 5):

```
    // create the innerHtml
    for (const slide in slides) {
      let theHtml =
        "<figure class='individual-slide'><img src='"
        + slides[slide].image
        + "' style = 'background-image: url("
        + slides[slide].image
        + ")'><figcaption>"
        + slides[slide].caption
        + "</figcaption></figure>";
}
```

Codepen of the above: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/vYYZKKB

I've thus attempted to use a classic for loop so I can add if statements for the nth item (i.e. if i = 0, add the first class, etc), although this doesn't seem to work even without them:

```
// create the innerHtml
for (const i = 0; i < Object.keys(slides).length; i++) {

  let theHtml =
    "<figure class='individual-slide'><img src='"
    + slides[slides][i].image
    + "' style = 'background-image: url("
    + slides[slides[i].image
    + ")'><figcaption>"
    + slides[slides[i].caption
    + "</figcaption></figure>";
}

console.log(theHtml);
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/oNNwLzR

So my questions are:

1. What's wrong with my code
2. How can I loop through each object but add the 'current', 'next' and 'previous' classes
3. And what's the best way of looping through objects like this?

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks for any help here

Comment: Not directly related, but why not use an array?

Comment: You can use `Object.entries(obj).map(([value, key], index) => {...generate html...}` if you need key value and index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tried the last example - you have some syntax errors in your code, e.g. `slides[slides[i].image`. Try using code editor with syntax highlight, e.g. VSCode

this would be the most straightfowrad way to fix 2nd pen

```
  Object.keys(slides).forEach((key, index) => {
    let additionalClass = ""
    if (index === 0) {
      additionalClass = " current"
    } else if (index === 1) {
      additionalClass = " next"
    } else if (index === 4) {
      additionalClass = " previous"
    }
    let theHtml =
      "<figure class='individual-slide"+additionalClass+"'><img src='"
      + slides[key].image
      + "' style = 'background-image: url("
      + slides[key].image
      + ")'><figcaption>"
      + slides[key].caption
      + "</figcaption></figure>";

    console.log(theHtml);

  })
```

so answering your 2nd question, you get index of the object passing 2nd parameter to the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) callback and use it in your logic to determine class name you want

3rd question: `Object.keys(slides)` to iterate over key names, or `Object.values(slides)` to iterate over values (`{ image: '...', caption: '...' }` object in your case)

Answer (score 1):

If you specifically want image 1, 2 and 5 to have unique classes, you can use if statements in your loop.

Your loops are perfectly fine btw.

So inside your loop:

```
if slide+1 == 1 || slide+1 == 2 || slide+1 == 5):
... add your classes
```

We add 1 since the index starts at 0.

Otherwise, a better solution is to add a key into your object that signifies that the object needs special treatment.

```
const slides = {
  "slide1": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/winbledon-centre-court.jpg",
    "caption": "Wimbledon Centre Court",
    "unique": True
  },
  "slide2": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/waterloo-train-station.jpg",
    "caption": "Waterloo Train Station"
  "unique": True
  },
  "slide3": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/test.jpg",
    "caption": "Das Lion"
  },
  "slide4": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/some4.jpg",
    "caption": "the four"
  },
  "slide5": {
    "image": "images/projects/authorising-engineers/some5.jpg",
    "caption": "no five",
    "unique": True
  }
}
```

And then use the same if statement as above, but just checking

```
if slides[slide].unique
```

Comment: thanks - although how is there nothing wrong with my 2nd code? it doesn't log anything into the console: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/oNNwLzR

Comment: It doesnt console log anything because the keyword "let" is bounded by the scope of the function. If you console log inside your loop, youll see something.